# Mysql : dumping a database fails

Tags: mysql

I regularly backup my database using the command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p <database_name> > <output_file>.sql
```

Today, this started failing repeatedly after ~1.9Go written to output file:

```
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `<problematic_table_name>` at row: 18556051
```

I tried some additional arguments proposed in other posts (`--quick --max_allowed_packet=512M --compress`) with no success. Even exporting this single problematic table instead of the whole DB always gives the same error, always with the same row number. So I suspect it is not connection timeout related but rather I may have file corruption.

So I ran:

```
mysql> use <database_name>;
mysql> CHECK TABLE <problematic_table_name>;
```

and after ~10s got

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

Here is what I get in the error log after I run `CHECK TABLE`:

```
2024-01-14T21:55:40.459566Z 1019 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use caching_sha2_password instead'
2024-01-14T21:55:57.686147Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
2024-01-14T21:55:57.686259Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 5 means 'Input/output error'
2024-01-14T21:55:57.686324Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./<database_name>/<problematic_table_name>.ibd: 'Linux aio' returned OS error 105. Cannot continue operation
2024-01-14T21:55:57.686359Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2024-01-14T21:55:58.270787Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 488539
2024-01-14T21:55:58.277043Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-01-14T21:55:58.545605Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-01-14T21:55:58.704719Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2024-01-14T21:55:58.713980Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2024-01-14T21:55:58.827925Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-01-14T21:55:58.827973Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-01-14T21:55:58.870209Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-01-14T21:55:58.870302Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
```

How can I repair my DB to be able to dump it again?

Comment: The first thing to look at would be the MySQL error log.

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for the tip, I added the log output.

Comment: How did you START your MySQL?  This URL may have some clues for you.
https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=41&q=mysql+error+2002&cvid=aeec5e5a5e8545e2974b91e25a1b77c6&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggAEAAYQDIGCAAQABhAMgYIARAAGEAyBggCEAAYQDIGCAMQABhAMgYIBBAAGEAyBggFEAAYQDIGCAYQABhAMgYIBxAAGEAyBggIEAAYQNIBCDM2ODNqMGoxqAIAsAIA&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=U531 
Your need to be running mysqld as a service, normally.

Comment: The server starts automatically at PC startup, like it was always the case, I haven't modified anything here. I also restarted it with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly was a file corruption. I forged a solution that worked:

- Stop any instance of application server that might me using the DB.
- Using bisection, narrow down the problematic interval `[t1,t2[` that is corrupted in `/var/lib/mysql/<database_name>/<problematic_table_name>.ibd` by exporting subintervals. Example (supposing there is a time column named `t` in `problematic_table_name`):

  `[Linux] mysqldump --opt -u root -p <database_name> <problematic_table_name> --where="t>='2023-08-15' AND t<'2023-08-16'" > tmp-from-2023-08-15-to-2023-08-16.sql`

and observing where MySQL crashes and where it survives.

- Export the sane data before & after the problematic interval using commands as above. You might need to divide into further subintervals as exporting the whole range `[<start of time>, t1[` and `[t2, <end of time>[` might still make MySQL crash.
- Open all exported `*.sql` files from previous step except the biggest one in text editor and delete the blocks `DROP TABLE...` and `CREATE TABLE...`, leaving just the `INSERT` block.
- Get rid of the corrupted table file:

  `mysql> drop table <problematic_table_name>` (this works, dropping just problematic rows doesn't; MySQL still crashes)
- Import the biggest `*.sql` file from before into `<database_name>`, this will recreate the table and insert rows.
- Import all the remaining files into `<database_name>`, this will add rows to the newly created table.
- Now we have a new healthy table and the whole DB can be dumped again successfully. Just the interval `[t1,t2[` is missing.

Extra:

I had an older dump file that covers `[t1,t2[` so I created a temporary database, imported that file into it, dumped that interval into file, deleted the blocks `DROP TABLE...` and `CREATE TABLE...` in text editor and imported the file into the newly created table in `<database_name>`. So I ended up with no data loss.

Done on MySQL Ver 8.0.35.